# Custom ajax error coming from C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to set custom error from C# to be displayed instead of `xhr.responseText` default as it is now.
How to pass `cSharpErrorMessage` to the ajax error?

Here is my C# code:

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static AjaxResult<string> GetAutoCompleteHtml(string termList)
        {
            const string cSharpErrorMessage = "Unable to generate autocomplete HTML.";

            try
            {
                //some logic
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //some logic
            }
        }
```

Here is my ajax function:

```
function StartAutoCompleteSearch(termsList) {
    if (termsList.length > 2) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Ajax/AjaxCalls.aspx/GetAutoCompleteHtml',
            type: 'POST',
            data: "{'termList':'" + termsList + "'}",
            global: false,
            datatype: JSON,
            success: function(response) {
                //some logic
            },
            error: function(xhr, response) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message + " Click OK to log back in ");
                window.location = "/login";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just throw an exception. Like this:

```
throw new Exception(cSharpErrorMessage);
```

Example with your code:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public static AjaxResult<string> GetAutoCompleteHtml(string termList)
 {
      const string cSharpErrorMessage = "Unable to generate autocomplete HTML.";

      try
      {
                //some logic
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
                //some logic to clean up and then throw exception
                throw new Exception(cSharpErrorMessage);
       }
   }
```

If you need to display the error message as the third argument in the ajax call, try this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 500;
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusDescription = cSharpErrorMessage;
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Your script:

```
error: function(xhr, response,errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown + " Click OK to log back in ");
                window.location = "/login";
            }
```

Comment: Uhmm... `errorThrown` is "undefined" when I try out your solution.

Comment: @mtashev: sorry, it should be status description. Check my updated answer

Comment: Still undefined when i changed it to `StatusDescription`. For some reason it never reaches the catch block in code behind. It just alerts me from ajax whenever there is error.

Comment: @mtashev: to reach the catch block, there must be an exception.

Comment: @mtashev: to test it, you could put your code outside the catch block.

Comment: It's outside. In chrome dev tools (Scope Variables) errorThrown: undefined. Message: "Thread was being aborted". It never gets to use cSharpErrorMessage.

Comment: @mtashev: you have a thread aborted exception else where and the code cannot reach cSharpErrorMessage. Fix that exception first and **ensure that the cSharpErrorMessage is executed**.

Comment: Thanks for the effort man, unfortunately this doesn't work for me and i'll have to take other route.

Comment: I currently throw new excepts from my C# code and have my ajax code display the message on my LOCAL machine, but when I put the code live the ajax returns the message: There was an error processing the request - Any ideas?

Comment: @harag: this could be because of custom error configuration in web.config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx, your live server could be replacing your exception with a generic message. In theory, we can throw an exception and the framework will automatically intercepts and send it as a http response to the client with status 500. If you need total control of the message being sent, you could try my second approach

Comment: @KhanhTO Many thanks, I did look into the problem more and found that the live server had custom errors set to remote only, changed this to off the live server started displaying the thrown error.

Comment: @harag: on live server, we should not display the detailed errors, as it may disclose some information.

Comment: @KhanhTO Agree. The type of errors I through are custom ones from the database stored procedures (e.g. "Email doens't exist in DB")